# ¿Cuáles son los daños que pueden ser causados por el mal uso de las herramientas de penTesting de Kali Linux?

Tags: linux

Leyendo la documentación de Kali Linux me topé con esto:

> In addition, misuse of security and penetration testing tools within a
>   network, particularly without specific authorization, may cause
>   irreparable damage...
>
> http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Me gustaría mucho exprimentar con las herramientas de Kali Linux, pero quiero entender bien ¿Cuáles son estos daños irreparables que puedo causar si lo uso mal o cometo un error? ¿Son daños solo de software o podría dañar el hardware?

Comment: Interesante la pregunta, ya di mi respuesta porque me gusta el tema, pero también di mi voto para cerrarla

Comment: @CésarBustíos una actitud un poco rara cuanto menos.

Comment: Si estás haciendo la pregunta posiblemente no deberías usar Kali Linux.

Comment: Hay usos correctos que un ignorante puede hacer de Kali Linux. Por ejemplo usarlo contra un ordenador de test propio.

Comment: _within a network, particularly **without specific authorization**, may cause irreparable damage..._ Por ejemplo, si lo haces en la red de tu empresa, sin pedir permiso, puede que te despidan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Después de leer un poco más sobre el tema he llegado a la conclusión de que sí, estas herramientas son peligrosas.
Están enfocadas a penetrar la seguridad de, por ejemplo, redes wireless.

Y el problema es que hoy día [redes wireless hay muchas](http://www.tiraecol.net/modules/comic/comic.php?content_id=280) y si no estás seguro de cómo está configurado por defecto un ataque de penetración a saber la que puedes liar en redes a las que no tienes derecho a acceder.

Estas herramientas pueden provocar fallos como la no disponibilidad de un servicio al probar cómo responde a ataques tipo DDOS. Hacer esto contra un servidor público de terceros puede provocarles graves daños económicos al no ser sus clientes capaces de usar sus servicios. Pero cuando lo haces contra tu propio ordenador privado de test no hay daños de que preocuparse. Es muy difícil encontrar daños que puedan provocarse que sean relevantes en un ordenador que estés dispuesto a formatear tras la prueba.

**Conclusión :**  los experimentos con gaseosa. Hazlos con un ordenador sin wireless y no conectado a internet. No hagas pruebas de campo hasta tener experiencia y sepas lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 4):

Pues, en mi opinión, es similar a la analogía que se hace con el cuchillo, puedes usarlo para cortar un limón, pero también lo puedes usar para cortarle la yugular a alguien, suficiente para terminar varios años o de por vida en alguna cárcel.

Recuerda que en un [test de penetración](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) estás atacando deliberadamente a tu víctima para identificar problemas de seguridad (riesgos, vulnerabilidades, etc.). Normalmente esto lo hacen empresas externas que han sido contratadas por el cliente, hacer esto sin consentimiento es considerado ilegal, nuevamente, te podrías ganar algún tiempo en la cárcel (si te descubren).

El penetration testing es considerado un tipo de hacking, las personas dedicadas al penetration testing son consideradas como hackers éticos (lo usan para fines exclusivamente profesionales) o de sombrero blanco. Incluso existen colores para los hackers (como en los magos de "El Señor de los Anillos"):

- [Sombrero blanco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security)) (los buenos)
- [Sombrero negro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hat) (los malos)
- [Sombrero gris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_hat) (ni buenos ni malos, algunos tienen problemas existenciales)

El tema es que existen herramientas muy potentes para hacer penetration testing las cuales puedes usarlas para fines buenos o malos y esa es la advertencia que intenta decirte Kali para que no termines en la cárcel.

Antes de decidir si quieres ser Luke Skywalker o Darth Vader, puedes leer el [Hacker Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_Manifesto).

Comment: Que tan feo puedo dañar mi maquina si utilizo las herramientas contra mi, osea contra el localHost, son daños reparables o puedo dejar mi computadora inservible ?

Comment: @AndrésMuñoz de que tipo de herramienta estamos hablando? Si por ejemplo usas una tipo Wireshark, no creo que tengas muchos problemas

Comment: Estas herramientas pueden provocar fallos como la no disponibilidad de un servicio al probar cómo responde a ataques tipo DDOS. Hacer esto contra un servidor público de terceros puede provocarles graves daños económicos al no ser sus clientes capaces de usar sus servicios. Pero cuando lo haces contra tu propio ordenador privado de test no hay daños de que preocuparse. Es muy difícil encontrar daños que puedan provocarse que sean relevantes en un ordenador que estes dispuesto a formatear tras la prueba.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos deberías añadir ese comentario como respuesta

Comment: Cesar, no puedes decidir tu color, debes parar la mente y reconocerlo.